# how to work with robotic manipulator?

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, microcontroller, ros-industrial, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have to work with one Kawasaki Robot arm. I am confused is there any developed package for the manipulator controller in ROS? These robotic arm come with one dedicated controller. in order to work with ROS in robot arm do I have to connect my computer with the controller or directly with the arm. I am really new in the field of robotic arm. I badly need this help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202311/how-to-work-with-robotic-manipulator?/) by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2015-02-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as I know there are no ROS packages that interface with Kawasaki industrial robot controllers.

You might want to send the [ROS-Industrial](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/swri-ros-pkg-dev) mailing list a message. They might have more information.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on 2015-02-03**:
hey thanks a lot. but I was searching randomly in ROS wiki and got this.
http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Industrial_Robot_Driver_Spec
and yes i have checked the community its still under process

**Comment by [Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/20363/robot/) on 2015-02-03**:
please let me know once you go through the website. is this of any help???